# Use visit() few times in one single test

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I am testing my Laravel 5.5 application with BrowserKitTestCase package. I receive an failure every time if I use visit() method more than one time in one single test, for example:

```
/* @test */
function my_simple_test(){
    $this->visit('product/1')
        ->see('Product #1');

    $this->visit('product/2')
        ->see('Product #2'); // assertion fails
}
```

but on the same time following tests are passed:

```
/* @test */
function my_simple_test_1(){
    $this->visit('product/1')
        ->see('Product #1');

/* @test */
function my_simple_test_2(){
    $this->visit('product/2')
        ->see('Product #2'); // assertion passes
}
```

Is it some possibility to use visit() few times in the same test? It was a case previously with Laravel 5.1.

**UPDATE**:
If I use `visit()` twice in the same test it looks like page is cached and on call `$this->visit('product/2')` I still see data from `/product/1`.

**UPDATE-2**
It happens only if I visit the same route with different parameters, test like following is passed:

```
/* @test */
function my_simple_test(){
    $this->visit('products')
        ->see('All Products');

    $this->visit('product/2')
        ->see('Product #2'); // assertion passes
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, controller instances are cached per route.

To call the same route with different parameters in the same test, application should be restarted between calls:

```
/* @test */
function my_simple_test(){
    $this->visit('product/1')
        ->see('Product #1');

    $this->refreshApplication();
    $this->setUp();

    $this->visit('product/2')
        ->see('Product #2'); // assertion passes
}
```